# intBitsToFloat method in Java VS C#?

Tags: c#, java, floating-point, bit

I'm getting the wrong number when converting bits to float in C#.

Let's use this bit `number= 1065324597`

In **Java**, if I want to convert from bits to float I would use `intBitsToFloat` method

```
int  intbits= 1065324597;
System.out.println(Float.intBitsToFloat(intbits));
```

**Output: `0.9982942`** which the *correct output the I want to get in C#*

---

However, in **C#** I used

```
int  intbits= 1065324597;
Console.WriteLine((float)intbits);
```

**Output: `1.065325E+09`**  Wrong!!

My question is how would you convert inbitsToFloat in C#?

**My attempt:** 
I looked to the documentation here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa987800(v=vs.80).aspx
but I still have the same trouble

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just casting is an *entirely* different operation. You need [`BitConverter.ToSingle(byte[], int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle.aspx) having converted the `int` to a byte array - and possibly reversed the order, based on the endianness you want. (EDIT: Probably no need for this, as the same endianness is used for both conversions; any unwanted endianness will just fix itself.) There's `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` for `double`, but no direct `float` equivalent.

Sample code:

```
int x = 1065324597;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

i want to add on top of what jon skeet said, that also, for big float, if you don't want the "E+" output you should do:

```
intbits.ToString("N0");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this...

```
var myBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(1065324597);
var mySingle = BitConverter.ToSingle(myBytes,0);
```

The BitConverter.GetBytes converts your integer into a four byte array. Then BitConverter.ToSingle converts your array into a float(single).