# Implement "IntBitsToFloat" function in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

In VB6 I am using

```
Private Type udt1
    i As Long
End Type
Private Type udt2
    f As Single
End Type

Private Function IntBitsToFloat(ByVal u As Long) As Double

    Dim n1 As udt1
    n1.i = u

    Dim n2 As udt2
    LSet n2 = n1

    IntBitsToFloat = n2.f

End Function
```

I am trying to find the equivalent in VB.NET but I did not find any.

Does anybody know it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one works, based on some test values from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format):

```vb
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>
Structure udt
    <FieldOffset(0)> Dim i As Integer
    <FieldOffset(0)> Dim f As Single
End Structure

Function IntBitsToFloat(ByVal u As Integer) As Single
    Dim x As udt
    x.i = u
    Return x.f
End Function
```

**EDIT**

Guess I should have searched first!  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18079107/2278086) for a less hacky version, which in VB.NET would be:

```vb
Function IntBitsToFloat(ByVal u As Integer) As Single
    Dim bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(u)
    Return BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0)
End Function
```

**UPDATE**

Looks like the hack with the `Structure` is significantly faster on my PC - e.g. over 100,000,000 iterations in LINQPad:

```
#1: 00:00:00.0553656
#2: 00:00:01.2785214
```

Comment: Thank you. Please give me some time to test it.